# Replacing any number of asterisks with NA in a data frame in R

Tags: r

I have data frame like this :

```
df<- c("***", "P","N", "GC*", "*CA","**G", "L","M")
```

I want to replace anything that has asterisks with NA no matter how many asterisks are there and in any position in my data.
I tried to do :

```
 na_if( "***")
```

It worked for the 3 asterisks but I don't know how to do it for the other values.
Can you please help me?

Answer (score 2):

```
df[grepl("[*]",df)] <- NA
```

Output:

```
NA  "P" "N" NA  NA  NA  "L" "M"
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. Does the `[ ]` square bracket means any thing with asterisks?. I applied this code on my data frame and it made everything NA, do you know why, please?

Comment: Yes. “*” is a regex meta character and needs to either be properly escaped with the proper number of backslashes which is this instance is probably 3, or to be enclosed in character class square brackets as was done here.

Comment: If we use `grepl("*",df)` will return `TRUE` for all elements of your vector; I enclosed in `[]` here to have it treated directly as a character